# What is a standard place to store uploaded files in API?

Tags: c#, api, file-upload, .net-core

I'm serving a .Net Core API project on a windows server that the published project is in a subfolder in `inetpub`.

My clients should upload some images and PDFs and API should store them forever. Currently I've created a subfolder called `Uploads` in project directory and save my files there.

```
inetpub
  |
  - MyWebsite
    |
    * web.config
    * appsettings.json
    * WebAPI.dll
    * WebAPI.Views.dll
    * ...
    - Uploads
      |
      + Images
      + Videos
      + PDFs
```

I use a CI/CD software to automatically publish my project. Sometimes it's possible that the person who writes CI command scripts do a mistake and when he is publishing the new version, deletes the `Uploads` folder too.

I'm asking about some best practice way to be comfortable and more secure to store these kind of files when writing an API.

Comment: I'd consider storing them somewhere like S3. This also means you can install your app across multiple servers (if you store them on the local file system then you basically are locked into a single server).

Comment: @mjwills I need to store the files on the same server. It's a CRM and may users have some limits on internet

Comment: You may want to be able to **serve** the file from the same server. That is different to having to **store** it there. Let's say your web server gets overloaded and you need to add a second web server. What are you going to do then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't say there is a "standard" place, as it depends on your requirements.

What is for sure, do not store them on the web server machine. Why:

- the machine may fail, and the files will be lost
- this approach doesn't scale to multiple machines (it is possible to share folders, but that brings more problems).

These files are basically data, and should be treated as such. Depending on your requirements, you may consider these options:

- External storage (a folder on web server mapped to external storage)
- No-SQL database
- Big data storage (e.g. Hadoop)
- Upload to CDN (e.g. S3)